# How to Combine and split values by delimiter?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that has a switch, `-Add`, allowing the addition of 1 role and 1 member (into that role) in a database at a time.

```
PS> script1.ps1 -Add Database1 role1 member1
PS> script1.ps1 -Add Database1 role1 member2
PS> script1.ps1 -Add Database1 role2 memberx
PS> script1.ps1 -Add Database1 role3
PS> script1.ps1 -Add Database1 role4 membery
```

It wont be practical to have to run that script everytime if there are more than 1 member or 1 roles/members to add a time. hence, i'd like to update my script with ***bulk addition of roles/members at once***, which would be helpful especially for a TFS use case, in which the user wont have to create multiple releases just to add a couple roles/members for the same database.

i am thinking of implementing a delimiter split, in which for every semicolon, that indicates the start of a new role, and any comma delimited members, all belong to one role unless a semicolon follows (not necessary if its the end of the input, unless it would be hard to achieve something like that with regex?)

pseudocode:

```
$RoleInput.Split(";") | ForEach { 

    $role = "$_";

    $MemberInput.Split(",") | ForEach { 

        $member = "$_";

        #-Add $DBName $role $member

    }
}
```

ultimately, i would like to achieve similar to the following:

```
PS> script1.ps1 -Add Database1 role1;role2;role3;role4 member1,member2;memberx;;membery
```

this means that for `role1, member1 and member2 would be added`
for `role2, memberx is added`, `for role3, no member is added`, and `for role 4, membery is added`

how would i achieve this correctly with regex to account for whitespaces, and end of input?

Comment: that paired list method is ... fragile. [*frown*] have you looked into passing in _objects_ that have the needed info? a PSCustomObject could have role/member info ... and you could pass in a collection of them.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i mean i'd love to use pscustomobject, but i dont know how a user would enter something like that either on console, or in input fields...if theer is a better way i can do this without splitting and delimiters, the better for me!

Comment: provide a UI to get that info and pass it to the script. that one script need not exist in isolation ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey unfortunately,  the UI is either console or TFS release, and TFS release only has variable and value fields. I dont want to hardcode a limited number of variable and value fields on TFS release, so the only way I thought of is to do it by the delimited method

Comment: perhaps you could use pairs? `-Add ARole:AMember, BRole:BMember` seems to be fairly easy to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save roles and members in a CSV

```
"Role","Members"
"role1","member1;member2"
"role2",
"role3","memberX"
```

then load the CSV using `Import-Csv`, split the member list at the chosen secondary delimiter (semicolons in the example above), and call your script with those arguments.

```
Import-Csv 'input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $role = $_.Role
    if ($_.Members) {
        $_.Members -split ';' | ForEach-Object { & script1.ps1 -Add $role $_ }
    } else {
        & script1.ps1 -Add $role
    }
}
```

If you can modify the [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-3.0) of your script you could change them to something like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Add,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='add', Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Role,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='add', Mandatory=$false)]
    [String[]]$Members = @()
)
```

so that the script accepts a list of members via a named parameter (you also need to adjust how the members are processed in the script, of course), and then call it like this:

```
Import-Csv 'input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $params = @{'Role' = $_.Role}
    if ($_.Members) { $params['Member'] = $_.Members -split ';' }
    & script.ps1 -Add @params
}
```

This second example uses [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) for passing the parameters to the script.

Comment: The problem is, this is limited. I cant pass a csv input in a TFS release variable/value.

Comment: @Cataster Then you may want to consider using a JSON string as input.

Comment: hmm...is it possible to convert an input like this role1;role2;role3;role4 member1,member2;memberx;;membery to JSON? because the users arent technical, so they wouldnt know how to pass in input in JSON format. i honestly thought that kind of input wouldnt be this hard to parse at all, but this seems more complicated than i thought lol. my plan was to meet with users and tell them for every semicolon it marks a new beginning, i.e. a new role, and for every comma delimited for members it falls all under one role by index of input. and it wouldve been as easy as that.

Comment: @Cataster Non-tech users should be given a frontend that allows them to pass in a CSV, which is then automatically converted to JSON and passed on to the backend.

Comment: unfortunately the only frontend we can push is the TFS release, that is the requirement. before i started building the release definition, i thought to myself, it would be ridiculous for users to have to create a release for every role/member being added to the same database. not only that, but we will have post-production deployment approval required for each release, so this will not be ideal because there will be a ton of approvals required for adding to the same database at once. hence why i was thinking of a way to allow bulk input, that is compatible with TFS release and user friendly.